# upload file and virtual filesystem database

Tags: sql, rest, upload, ftp, filesystems

I would like to upload a big file to a server and keep path and metadata in a database. 
For instance :

```
upload file.bam with param = { user:"boby", file_score=34 }
```

And store in the database :

```
Table files 
{
  path : "/uploads/files/file.bam",
  user : "boby" ,
  file_score :34   

}
```

What the best approch ? 
Mixing REST API with FTP  ?
Run Sql query after ftp upload ? 
Is there some tools to do this job ?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about FTP. The theoretical overheads of HTTP are not worth the inconvenience of FTP (let alone of FTPS / SFTP).

HTTP is faster for small transfers and for larger ones, speed mostly depends on the lower layers (TCP…). Also, HTTP requires only one port (80, or 443 for HTTPS) and thus is much easier to use when you have to deal with firewalls, NAT… It also provides a lot of features that aren't available to FTP (compression, authentication…). There's a reason why WebDAV is built on top of HTTP.

Major players all send both metadata and content over HTTP :

- [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) ;
- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put) ;
- [OpenStack Swift](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/api/object_api_v1_overview.html) ;
- [OwnCloud](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/index.html).

For inspiration regarding an API to upload both metadata and big files reliably, I suggest you look at how Google handles [resumable uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable).